# Expectation of $(X|Z)$ where $Z=X+Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need help to solve the following problem.

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ have geometric distribution with parameter $p$. Compute $E(X|X+Y=k)$ for all $k = 2,3,4,...$

This is how i attempted so far.

Let $Z = X + Y$
$$
\begin{align}
P(Z=z) &= \sum_{x=0}^z P(X=x,Y=y) \\
&= \sum_{x=0}^z P(X =x) P(Y=z-x) \\
&= \sum_{x=0}^z p (1-p)^x p (1-p)^{z-x} \\
&= \sum_{x=0}^z p^2 (1-p)^z \\
&= p^2(1-p)^z (z+1)
\end{align}
$$

\begin{align}
P(X|Z) &= \frac{P(X=x,Z=z)} {P(Z=z)} \\
&= \frac{(1-p)^xp(1-p)^zp} {p^2(1-p)^z (z+1)} \\
&= \frac{(1-p)^x} {(z+1)} \\
\end{align}

So,

\begin{align}
E(X|Z=z) &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x \frac{(1-p)^x} {(z+1)} \\
\end{align}

And do not know how to proceed further..Help please..

Answer (score 1):

The question is not solvable unless one assumes that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. On the other hand, if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. (and integrable), there is no need to specify the common distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to solve the question.

To wit, note that $E[X\mid X+Y]=u(X+Y)$ for some measurable function $u$. Since the joint distributions of $(X,X+Y)$ and $(Y,X+Y)$ coincide and since conditional expectations depend only on the distributions, $E[Y\mid X+Y]=u(X+Y)$ as well.

Summing these yields $E[X+Y\mid X+Y]=2u(X+Y)$. Since $E[Z\mid Z]=Z$ for every $Z$, $2u(X+Y)=X+Y$, hence 
$$
E[X\mid X+Y]=\tfrac12(X+Y).
$$
In particular, for every $z$, 
$$
E[X\mid X+Y=z]=\tfrac12z.
$$

Comment: Thanks Did, You are right. X and Y are independent and have geometric distribution. So, is E(X|X+Y) equal to 1/2 (X+Y)?

Comment: ?? Please read.

Comment: Hi Did,

The main reason is I am still lacking knowledge to understand the fact that the joint distributions of (X,X+Y) and (Y,X+Y) coincides. Will you be able to guide so that I can learn this gap. Thanks

Comment: First show that the distributions of U=(X,Y) and W=(Y,X) coincide. Thus the distributions of g(U) and g(V) coincide, for every function g. Finally, use g(r,s)=(r,r+s).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to be able to evaluate the sum of the form

$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} xr^x$

where $r<1$.

You start from $ \sum_0^\infty  r^x = 1/(1-r)$ and differentiate both sides

to get $ \sum xr^{x-1} = 1/(1-r)^2$. Multiplying by $r$, you get your answer.

Comment: This is how i continue my existing exercise. Please correct me if I am still wrong.

E(X|Z=z) = 1/(z+1) (1-p)/p^2 

then substitute back z= x+y = k
E(X|X+Y=k) = 1/(k+1) (1-p)/p^2